# JS function more compact

Tags: javascript

I have a function who use coordinates,

I looking for a way to have a DRY code

this is a part of my code :
https://codepen.io/sebastiancz/pen/LYGLXjW?editors=1010

a part a my code

```
 const coordinate = {"x": x, "y": y};
                this.tilesCoordinates.push(coordinate);
                const max = this.tilesCoordinates.length - 1;
                const curr = this.tilesCoordinates[max];
                const prev = this.tilesCoordinates[max - 1];
                ....
```

thanks for your help

Comment: So you wrote the code and it does work?

Comment: If your code works as intended, then this question is more suitable for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: `curr` is the same as `coordinate`.

Comment: There isn't enough R here to worry about DRY.

Comment: @trincot when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it is missing context.

Comment: My code is working well, and I don't think it need context to made a refactoring.
I just need to know if it's possible or not ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its too broad for Stack Overflow